# Changing a text view on one class with another class

Tags: android, class, listview, dynamic, textview

I am building a calculator with a `listview` that is set dynamically. When its being built(with calculations), an `onclickListener` is set to each item to delete the row. This is all done with an AdapterClass. I have my MainClass that holds all the information. In this class, it has a running total of my items. This running total has a class that will add/subtract/retrieve my running total. The running total (as of now) is only set when the "CALCULATE" button is pressed.  When I delete an item (row/calculation) I need it to update my running total in my main class. Keep in mind, the `onClick` used to delete the items is in my `AdapterClass`, not my `MainClass`. If you need further explanation let me know.

**A better explanation**

[image]

**MainActivity**

```
//This is called in my CALCULATE on click, after all the calulations have been made. THE ONLY PLACE THAT THE RUNNING TOTAL GETS CHANGED
newList=new ArrayList<Calculations>();

Calculations info = new Calculations();

info.SetType("Slab figure "+figureCount);
info.SetFigure(width+"x"+length+"x"+depth);
info.SetFigureAmount(String.format("%.2f",CubicYd)+"");
newList.add(info);
currentTotal.add(CubicYd);

total.setText(String.format("Total: "+"%.2f",currentTotal.getRunningTotal())+" Cubic Yards");

if(newList!=null&&newList.size()>0)

{
    newAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    newAdapter.add(newList.get(0));
    i++;
}

newAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**runningTotal**

```
public class runningTotal {

    double runningTotal = 0.0;

    public double add(double newAmount) {
        runningTotal = runningTotal + newAmount;
        return runningTotal;
    }

    public double sub(double newAmount) {
        runningTotal = runningTotal - newAmount;
        return runningTotal;
    }

    public double getRunningTotal() {
        return runningTotal;
    }

    public void setRunningTotal() {
        runningTotal = 0.0;
    }
}
```

**ListAdapter**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Calculations> {

    runningTotal currentTotal = new runningTotal();
    Calculations c = new Calculations();
    private Context appContext = null;
    private ArrayList<Calculations> items = null;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Calculations> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.appContext = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) appContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        c = items.get(position);
        if (c != null) {
            //Set the calculations to the list view
            TextView type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
            TextView figure = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFullFigure);
            TextView amount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_id);
            layout.setTag(position);

            //set on click to the layout that deletes the line.
            layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String pos = view.getTag().toString();
                    int _position = Integer.parseInt(pos);
                    currentTotal.sub(Double.parseDouble(c.getFigureAmount()));
     <----This is where I need to update the textView "total" in my mainAcitivity----->
                    items.remove(_position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(appContext, "The amount to be released is " + Double
                            .parseDouble(c.getFigureAmount()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
            if (type != null) {
                type.setText(c.getType());
            }
            if (figure != null) {
                figure.setText(c.getFigure());
            }
            if (amount != null) {
                amount.setText(c.getFigureAmount());
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

**Calculations**

```
private String type = "";
private String figure = "";
private String figureTotal = "";

public void SetType(String type){
    this.type = type;
}
public String getType(){
    return this.type;
}

public void SetFigure(String figure) {
    this.figure = figure;
}
public String getFigure(){
    return this.figure;
}

public void SetFigureAmount(String figureTotal){
    this.figureTotal = figureTotal;
}

public String getFigureAmount(){
    return this.figureTotal;
}
```

**UPDATE / this my `CustomListAdapter` with a `ViewHolder` from Beginner**

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,           ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

     if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)appContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText(currentTotal.getRunningTotal()+"");

    c = items.get(position);
    if (c != null){
        //Set the calculations to the list view
        TextView type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvType);

        TextView figure = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFullFigure);
        TextView amount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_id);
        layout.setTag(position);



        //set on click to the layout that deletes the line.

        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String pos = view.getTag().toString();
                int _position = Integer.parseInt(pos);
                double newTotal;
                double oldTotal;
                oldTotal = Double.parseDouble(c.getFigureAmount());
                newTotal = currentTotal.getRunningTotal() - oldTotal;
                currentTotal.setRunningTotal(newTotal);


                holder.text.setText("total after delete" );

                items.remove(_position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        if(type!=null) {
            type.setText(c.getType());
        }
        if(figure!=null){
            figure.setText(c.getFigure());
        }
        if(amount !=null){

            amount.setText(c.getFigureAmount());
        }

    }
    return v;
}

static class ViewHolder{

    TextView text;
}
}
```

I get `nullPointer` in the line

> holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);

Comment: which textview you need to change from which class??..

Comment: I need to change the text view named `total` in the `MainActivity`. It will be done with the list adapter class in the `onClick`

Comment: You have any other activity class in your project?

Comment: yes, only one, I have a class called Calculations. Ill post it. See the edits

Comment: create a object of the main activity in Adapterclass and use settext method. make sure your total is defined as public

Comment: Your going to have to post an example. That way I understand better, and I can give you credit.

Comment: check out the answer, i have given an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you're using the on click for a view inside your list, if you call list.setOnItemClickListener and wire up your onclick in your activity, rather then layout.setOnClickListener on your adapter. Note I'm not saying you can't do what you're asking to do, but this would be the recommended way to fix it.

something like this (on the main Activity where the text view lives):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Calculations c = (Calculations) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        currentTotal.sub(Double.parseDouble(c.getFigureAmount()));
        total.setText(String.format("Total: "+"%.2f",currentTotal.getRunningTotal())+" Cubic Yards");
        items.remove(_position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(appContext, "The amount to be released is " + Double
                .parseDouble(c.getFigureAmount()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

though you never posted where you're setting your adapter so I'm not sure what your list view is called.

Comment: I see what your saying. I'm not sure I know how to do it. Do you have Any links or examples so I can research it?

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter class use a holder and try to update the veiws using the holder.. here is an example

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary
    // calls
    // to findViewById() on each row.
    ViewHolder holder;
    // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no
    // need
    // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView
    // supplied
    // by ListView is null.

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, null);
        // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
        // views
        // we want to bind data to.
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
        // and the ImageView.

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
    holder.name.setText(myElements.get(id));
    holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView  name;
    ImageView icon;
}
```

So Now, suppose you want to update `textview` called `total`

**Step 1**
define total in ViewHolder class like

static class ViewHolder{
/* Define all your view's to update here*/
TextView total;

}

**Step 2**

create a instance of ViewHolder in getView() method.
ViewHolder holder;

**Step 3**
use a holder to update your textview in onclick method

holder.total.setText("The text u want to set");

Comment: What am I supposed to have in my ViewHolder class?

Comment: The view which you need to inflate

Comment: And how am I supposed to access that text view? I need a better explanation

Comment: This all would work if the text view I was trying to change wasnt in my `MainActivity` class. That's my problem. I can't access that inside my adapter class